# ln -s create needed dir

Tags: bash, grep, mkdir, gnu-parallel, ln

```
echo "super-super.show.s01.e01" | grep -oPi '(?<=-)[\w\W]+(?=\.s\d\d)|s\d\d|e\d\d' | parallel -N3 ln -sf ~/super-super.show.s01.e01 ~/TV/{1}/{2}/{3}
# tries to make ~/TV/super.show/s01/e01 failes due to no such file or directory
```

How can i write my code so it creates the needed dir?

if there is no **e01** in the string it tries to create link to:

```
~/TV/super.show/s01/{3}
```

How can i write my code so it then creates link to:

```
~/TV/super.show/s01
```

Comment: Do you really need `parallel` to create symlinks? If you rewrite your code into something readable using a `while` loop, then you can simply use `mkdir -p`.

Comment: Well im not quite sure. I want to create links where i use the output of `grep` to create the subdirectory to the links and i managed to do that with `parallel`. Can this be done easier?

Comment: @mklement0 I've tried with `xargs -i{}`, but then i only get the `{}` variable to us for several outputs from `grep`... as far as i know.

Comment: `xargs` will f.ck you over if you use names like '>>super<< 12" star*show.s01.e01'. GNU Parallel will not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
echo '>>super<< 12" star*show.s01.e01.mp4' |
  parallel --rpl '{dir} s:\.(s\d\d):/$1:; s:\.(e\d\d):/$1:; s/\....$//;' mkdir -p ~/TV/{dir}';' ln -s {} ~/TV/{dir}
```

Comment: Guess I'll have to do it this way hoped i could do all i wanted in one line.

Comment: Nicely done. GNU `parallel` calls this method of modifying the input a [Perl expression replacement string](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Replacement-strings).